# Corebluetooth changes in reading characteristics value

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

i'm currently migrating my project from swift 2.3 to swift 3 and I'm confuse with one thing. in swift 2.3 i can simply use

```
 print("value \(characteristic.value!)")
```

and it would print the value i received value 61. But in swift 3 it would print something like 1 bytes. In order to get the value i have tried with the command

```
print("value \(characteristic.properties.rawvalue)")
```

With this command it return me the value. But why do Apple change this?

EDIT

i wonder if it is a bug? i'm using Xcode8.2.1 and swift 3 the command

```
characteristic.value!
```

would not return me the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`characteristic.value` return a `Data` type value. Here's how I get the data.

```
        if let dataBytes = characteristic.value {
            if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: "FFF1") {
                 print(dataBytes)
            } else if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: "FFF2") {
                print(dataBytes)
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi, yah it is a Data type, but when i print the value, it shows "1 bytes" but that is not what i wan't.

Comment: You can convert to whatever value you need. In other words, if the return value is string type, you may use `let value = String(bytes: dataBytes, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, but what if i need the raw value before encoding?

Comment: `let data = Data(bytes: [0x12])` and `print(data.hashValue) = 18 ` is this what you want?

Comment: oh yah, that is what i'm looking for, thank you very much! btw, does apple provide any document or link related to this? I have been trying to figure it out but i could not find any relevant document.